# I'm making a scrabble board game and I don't know how to generate random 7 alphabets, every time the player uses their alphabet

Tags: javascript, html

A


B


C


D


E


F


G

these are the starting 7 letters of an alphabet that are being used and I want to know how to generate more letters after these have been used. So basically a letter generator. thanks

Comment: So your starting letters (not alphabet) are hard coded?

Comment: Your question is tagged with both `javascript` and `html`, but no code was posted with your question. Please include your current code attempt so we have a better sense of what you're trying to do. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more info.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a string containing all of the letters you can pick from. `const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` Next you want to get a random number using the `Math.random()*26` If you had a different length string you would just put whatever length your string is instead of 26. Now you want to get a letter from your string at the index of your random number using `letters.charAt()` When you combine these together you get this.

```js
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var randomLetter = letters.charAt(Math.random() * 26);

console.log(randomLetter)
```

Comment: Why have you assigned `letters` with `const` and `randomLetter` with `var`.

Comment: That does not make any sense.

Comment: I assigned letters with const because the letters to pick from shouldn't have to change. I assigned randomLetter with var because you might want to pick a different random letter later.

Comment: So you should use `let` instead.

Comment: thank you for the code. But the alphabets do not appear on the browser